# Pepper Robot doesn't boot up properly

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

I got my hands on a Pepper Robot, but I have some problems with it.
Sometimes when I boot him up he is in a very weird state where the tablet is totally black (in python it can't even find `ALTabletService`) and autonomous life is also not working and can't even be started with Choregraphe. Nonetheless tho i can still connect to him and Services Like `ALTextToSpeech`, `ALDialog` or `ALRobotPosture` work perfectly fine. When it happened yesterday I just went home and when I came back today he worked totally fine for like 2 hours until I restarted him after a break and got the same problem again. I dont know whats wrong with him. Should I do a factory reset or is that useless? I would appreciate an other solution cause there are already many files and behaviors in his Memory. [This is the robot 10 minutes after I turned him on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmxeO.jpg) He doesn't react on touch or anything else in this state.

Thank you very much guys!

Edit: here is some code I tested

```
import qi

session = qi.Session()
session.connect("robot ip")
tts = session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
tts.setParameter("speed", 120)
tts.setLanguage("English")
tablet = session.service("ALTabletService")
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Test/Nao/scripts/naoqiTest.py", line 8, in <module>
    tablet = session.service("ALTabletService")
RuntimeError: Cannot find service 'ALTabletService' in index
```

Comment: and also his tablet is black the whole time he is booting up.

Comment: Where's your code? What do you mean "python cant even find the ALTabletService"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jim i edited my post so it contains some code example now

Comment: It seems NAOqi could not boot up completely. To figure out why, you can check NAOqi logs using `journalctl` (when logged on the robot using `ssh`). Please export these logs into a pastebin to share it.