# Pepper robot's tablet is black, no `ALTabletService`

Tags: pepper

I ran my code (the code had a bug that wrong "path" to show the image on the Pepper tablet), I fixed my code's issue, but blocked Pepper. After I rebooted pepper robot again, the Pepper tablet was totally black, I called the `ALTabletService`, it shows "cannot find ALTabletService".

I used `qicli` to check all services, I cannot find `ALTabletService`. It seems the TabletService is crashed. I tried to do many times special reboot, it still did not work. I noticed there was a similar issue as me on stackoverflow ([Pepper Robot doesn't boot up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775909/pepper-robot-doesnt-boot-up-properly)), but there is no good answer.

[Here are `journalctl` logs from the robot](https://gist.github.com/victorpaleologue/c714227489fb1bd1e44aecec11ba45dd).

Comment: Please provide logs from `journalctl`.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue where the screen was black but the backlight was always on (even when the robot was powered off). We tried to perform a factory reset, a special startup and reseting the tablet but nothing worked.

However, letting the robot run completely out of battery to force the tablet to shut down fixed it for us.

Comment: thanks for you reply, I tried to plug out and plug in the tablet, and turn on the robot, the tablet works, however, the ALTabletService api still doesnot work. Once I turned off the robot, and turn on again without plug out and plug in the tablet, the table is black, so everytime, before i turn on the robot, i have to plug in and plug out the tablet, then tablet works, but still the ALTabletService api doesnot work at all. @Blatoy, the ALTabletService api can work in your side?

Comment: @NaLi we also have to completely turn off the robot (there is a power switch inside the right leg) every time we restarted it for the tablet to work. We were able to display images on the tablet using the "Show Image" block in Choregraphe. I think it uses the ALTabletService but I am not 100% sure and unfortunately I do not have access to the robot anymore.

Comment: Hi @Blatoy, you mentioned " (there is a power switch inside the right leg) " ---- Pepper robot does not have right or left legs, you mean Nao robot?

Comment: @NaLi sorry I meant to say the right panel, located on the "legs" of Pepper.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me once after the tablet was grabbed and pulled away from the robot (without success).

After I turned off the robot normally, pushed the tablet towards the torso and slightly down, and then restarting the robot, it worked again.

But at this stage I cannot tell if I really figured out the cause or if it just luck.